# shiny server isn't interacting with any inputs

Tags: r, shiny, shiny-server

I'm having a weird problem where my shiny app works perfectly well on my local machine, but when I try to run it off a shiny server (on an EC2 instance), the inputs stop working. When I try to reference inputs in, for example, if statements, it will produce an error saying:

> Error in if: argument is of length zero

It's like the inputs don't even exist.

Even something as simple as this code will only return "You've chosen the tool" as the text.

```
library(shinyWidgets) 
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(sidebarLayout(
                  sidebarPanel(width = 3,
                    radioGroupButtons("tool", label = h4(strong("Select a Tool:")),
                                      choices = c("Records", "Team Sheets"),
                                      selected = "Records")
                  ),
                  mainPanel(width = 9,
                            htmlOutput("chosen_tool"))
  )
)

server <-function(input, output) {

  output$chosen_tool <- renderText({paste("You've chosen the", input$tool, "tool.", sep = " ")})

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

I've double checked to make sure that the environment is clear on my local machine, and all packages are up to date on the server.

Comment: Have you loaded the necessary libraries for the code? library(shinyWidgets) library(shiny)

Comment: Yes. I should have mentioned that above, but they're in the code.